# calculate cosine in xsl version 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have two variables with longitude and latitude values. 
Now i want to calculate these variables into x and y values, but i need the cosine function for that. XSL only supports plus, divide and so on...

How i can calculate cosine in XSL 1.0?

```
<xsl:variable name="lat" select="some value"/>
<xsl:variable name="lon" select="some value"/>

<xsl:variable name="x" select="?? do some crazy calculate with cosine ??"/>
<xsl:variable name="y" select="?? do some crazy calculate with cosine ??"/>
```

Thanks for Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the FXSL 1.0 library from Dimitre Novachev includes pure XSLT 1.0 code to calculate trigonometric functions. An extension function would probably be faster, but a pure XSLT implementation is more portable.

Answer (score 2):

There is no function for cosine in standard XSLT 1.0, but check out [EXSLT](http://www.exslt.org/), specifically the [`math:cos()`](http://exslt.org/math/functions/cos/index.html) function:

```
Implementer Page: math.cos.html
Function Package: math.cos.zip

function syntax

number math:cos(number)
The math:cos function returns cosine of the passed argument in radians.
```

Answer (score 2):

If your processor doesn't support the EXSLT math:cos() function, you can still compute it quite easily using the [Taylor power series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series).

Answer (score 1):

Or look at your processor's documentation for how to write/invoke extension functions. Some processors (such as Apache Xalan) make invoking Java library functions fairly simple.